# How to retrieve input values and print to console?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would like to print in the console.log the values referring to the input username and input password. See my form:

```
<form>
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>    

        <button ion-button color="secondary" clear full style="font-style: bold; text-align: center;">Forgot Password?</button>

        <button ion-button color="secondary" type="submit" full>Login</button>

    </ion-list>
</form>
```

How to retrieve input and print values in the console next of clicking the login button?

Comment: i recommend to follow this blog https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/ about forms will help you

Comment: You are using angular 2 right?

Comment: @suraj Angular Core: 2.2.1

Comment: ok..angularjs tag is for 1.x , use angular 2 for 2.x related questions

Comment: @suraj Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use form builder, learn more about Reactive Forms in Angular https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formVar" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>    

        <button ion-button color="secondary" clear full style="font-style: bold; text-align: center;">Forgot Password?</button>

        <button ion-button color="secondary" type="submit" full>Login</button>

    </ion-list>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  formVar: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formVar = this.fb.group({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    });

  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.formVar.value);
  }

}
```

the difference between ngSubmit vs submit event: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

> However, ngSubmit ensures that the form doesn’t submit when the
>   handler code throws (which is the default behaviour of submit) and
>   causes an actual http post request. Let’s use ngSubmit instead as this
>   is the best practice:

Comment: I started this week and I hardly know anything. Thank You! Great!  It worked. I am PT-BR.

Comment: you're welcome. try to read more about Angular document in this official site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/